# How can I grant permissions on tables created in the future to members of a particular role?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I would like to create a role which will be granted to several individual users. This role should have full permissions on all tables, sequences, functions, etc. in a specified schema. When new tables, etc. are created in that schema in the future, I do not want to modify permissions - members of this role should by default have permissions for these newly created objects. How can I do this?

Currently, I am able to grant permissions on existing tables, but if I drop and re-create them I get the error `permission denied for relation my_table`.

Here is my role definition script:

```
create role my_role;
grant all on database my_database to my_role;
grant all privileges on schema public to my_role;
grant all privileges on all tables in schema public to my_role;
grant all privileges on all sequences in schema public to my_role;
grant all privileges on all functions in schema public to my_role;

alter default privileges in schema public
    grant all privileges on tables to my_role;
alter default privileges in schema public
    grant all privileges on sequences to my_role;
alter default privileges in schema public
    grant all privileges on functions to my_role;

grant my_role to user1;
grant my_role to user2;
```

If `user1` creates a table, I'd like `user2`  (and other members of `my_role`) to have permissions on it, but that is currently not the case.

I am new to Postgres (coming from MySQL) - thanks in advance for any assistance, and my apologies if I am wildly misunderstanding these concepts somehow.

Comment: Docs: [ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)

Comment: I've reviewed this page but am still stuck. I modified the question to clarify which user is creating tables and which user seems to be missing permissions.

Comment: Try `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO my_role;`. Any difference?

Comment: Keep in mind `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` only affects **new** tables, not existing ones, so you want to execute it before creating the tables.

Comment: I'm having this same problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the user**2**, or user**N**, who has role **my_role** to have access to the **future** tables of user**1**,
you must run the code below under user**1** (who creates new tables),
because ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES...
works only for objects **by that user under whom you run** ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES...

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO my_role;
```